Is possible to break columns inside a song and center the chorus?
This is my code, I would like to change the layout page and have 6 verses in two columns and then the chorus page wide centered after all the verses. As you can see I am using \usepackage[chorded]
%
% Example based on documentation for the songs project:
% http://songs.sourceforge.net/
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage\[chorded\]{songs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\songpos{3}
\usepackage\[a4paper, total={7.5in, 8in}\]{geometry}
\noversenumbers
\renewcommand{\chorusjustify}{\justifyleft}

\begin{document}
\songcolumns{2}
%\flushbottom
%\twocolumn\[\]
\begin{songs}{}
\pagepreludes
\beginsong{Para los ojos más bellos}\[by={Paz Onofre y Juan Carlos Carabajal},
                     sr={},
                     cr={},
                     index={}\]
\beginverse
    Lun\[D\]ita alúmbrame con t\[A\]us destell\[D\]os
    y ay\[D\]údame a encon\[G\]trar los ojos tan bell\[A\]os
    Lun\[D\]ita ayúdam\[G\]e que su\[A\]eño con ell\[D\]os
\endverse

\beginverse
    Apenitas los vi ardió en mi pecho
    La llama del amor que estaba durmiendo
    Lo despertó el fulgor de unos ojos negros.
\endverse

\beginverse
    Que haremos para estar por siempre unidos
    Si Dios nos hizo andar distintos caminos
    Porqué tuvo que ser tan cruel el destino.
\endverse

\beginchorus
    Y cuando sola estés con mi recuerdo
    No te olvides mi bien, que mucho te quiero
    Y esperándote están mis brazos abiertos.
\endchorus
\brk
\beginverse

    Son tus ojos mujer los que amo tanto
    No los quisiera ver nublados de llanto
    Que me entristezco yo y es triste mi canto.
\endverse

\beginverse
    Dios quiera que al final de nuestras vidas
    Podamos corazón borrar las heridas
    Que nos dejó a los dos tu ausencia y la mía.
\endverse

\beginverse
    Y para unirnos más un tierno niño
    Moreno como voz de miel leche y trigo
    El fruto de tu amor y tanto cario.
\endverse

\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}][1]][1]


Why did you replace [...] with \[...\] everywhere?  The latter is for math display mode.

Normally paracol aligns columns using \switchcolumn*, but using it here had odd effects on \beginsong ... \endsongcontinuity.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*
\songpos{3}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7.5in, 8in}]{geometry}
\noversenumbers
\renewcommand{\chorusjustify}{\justifyleft}
\newsavebox{\mytitle}

\begin{document}
\songcolumns{0}
\begin{paracol}{2}
%\raggedbottom

\begin{songs}{}
\pagepreludes
\beginsong{Para los ojos más bellos}
  [by={Paz Onofre y Juan Carlos Carabajal},
  r={},cr={},index={}]

\beginverse
    Lun[D]ita alúmbrame con t[A]us destell[D]os
    y ay[D]údame a encon[G]trar los ojos tan bell[A]os
    Lun[D]ita ayúdam[G]e que su[A]eño con ell[D]os
\endverse

\beginverse
    Apenitas los vi ardió en mi pecho
    La llama del amor que estaba durmiendo
    Lo despertó el fulgor de unos ojos negros.
\endverse

\beginverse
    Que haremos para estar por siempre unidos
    Si Dios nos hizo andar distintos caminos
    Porqué tuvo que ser tan cruel el destino.
\endverse

\switchcolumn
\vspace*{0.7\baselineskip}% fudge factor

\beginverse
    Son tus ojos mujer los que amo tanto
    No los quisiera ver nublados de llanto
    Que me entristezco yo y es triste mi canto.
\endverse

\beginverse
    Dios quiera que al final de nuestras vidas
    Podamos corazón borrar las heridas
    Que nos dejó a los dos tu ausencia y la mía.
\endverse

\beginverse
    Y para unirnos más un tierno niño
    Moreno como voz de miel leche y trigo
    El fruto de tu amor y tanto cario.
\endverse

\beginchorus
    Y cuando sola estés con mi recuerdo
    No te olvides mi bien, que mucho te quiero
    Y esperándote están mis brazos abiertos.
\endchorus
\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}

